# Android TV Portrait App

Tags: android, layout, portrait, television

I am new in android development . I am building an app for Android TV . I already design the landscape layout but Android Studio is not allowing me to design Portrait Layout for TV !
Why is this happening ?
Please help me with some solid detail(information).

Thankyou in advanc

Regards.

Comment: Few people are going to turn their TV on its side to run your app. Beyond that, please explain in detail what "not allowing me to design Portrait Layout for TV" means.

Comment: it mean ! When we designing the layout . In XML file Preview , there is a tool bar on the top where u can select the mode (Landscape / portrait) . In TV app case , There is only Landscape Option but not portrait . Therefore ! i can not design my portrait mode

Comment: You cannot use the graphical layout editor to preview portrait mode. Presumably, that is because Android TV devices do not support portrait mode, AFAIK. Switch your preview device to something other than a TV.

Comment: if i change preview device then defenatly ! Deisgn will not be same on TV . Then what should i do ?

Comment: Do not worry about portrait mode on Android TV. Again, AFAIK, it will never be used. Or, simply set up the portrait layout using the XML, ignoring the preview.

Comment: You'll need to really think about how your app will be used on a TV.  Designing for a TV isn't the same as designing for a Tablet.  Don't treat it as such.   You don't necessarily need to use the Leanback Library for TV.  If you don't then you can get your standard ActionBar and Toolbar layouts, but you have to really make sure everything works with a D-Pad and you control where focus should go to next.  TVs are not large tablets.

Answer (score -2):

In Android TV app landscape mode is enough.!!! No one will rotate his TV and you don't need to to create a portrait design for your application.

Comment: ho many that kind of people you know ??? and how many TV apps you created with portrait mode ?

Comment: just because you dont know anyone that does it doesnt mean they arent out there, when developing an application you need to think of every possible outcome